# My phone- HTC One V reboots when I insert my SDCARD

Tags: external-sd, reboot, htc-one-v

I have a HTC One V that reboots whenever I have my 8GB SDCard (Sandisk) inserted. Currently it has 2.5GB data in it. Once i remove the sdcard, my phone works fine.

I have many apps and photos on my SDCARD. I am able to read the sd card contents on my windows PC. I formatted the SDCARD and copied the contents back, but the reboot problem persists.

What else can I try to get rid of those reboots?

I went through [this forum](http://androidforums.com/htc-one-v/687014-reboot-loop-sd-card.html) and one way to overcome is to fool your phone stating part of your sd card as internal memory itself. Can it be done without rooting your phone?

Answer (score 0):

No, that "fooling" needs deeper access into the system, and thus requires root.

But apart from that, I'd recommend trying it with a different card. Important: *not* the same brand and size and class; try e.g.

- a card from a different manufacturer
- switch between classes (class-6 is good enough, it does not have to be class-10)

There are several incompatibilites reported here and there, and in most cases a card from a different brand worked fine. Maybe you can borrow some from friends if you cannot effort to buy a bunch.

I always buy microSD with SD adapter, so in case of incompatibility I can use it in my camera or other devices, and the buy was no loss in any case.

Comment: Please check if that solves your issue. If it does, it would be nice to accept the answer -- which then helps other possibly affected users to recognize the solution as such. Thank you!